# No Audio on Lubuntu [booted alongside Windows]

Tags: sound, lubuntu

I have installed **Lubuntu 14.04 LTS** in Virtual Box on my Windows 7 desktop.

> Amd Sempron (TM) 145 Processor
>
> 1GB DDR2 800 MHz PC 6400 of total 4GB of system RAM
>
> Audio adapter ICH-Intel 82801AA-ICH

After the installation, there were no audio. I searched here in the community and saw certain alsa mixer shell commands which didn't succeed even after the installaion. However, I have searched again and installed pavucontrol and still the problem persists.

Kindly advise what I can do to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. Open `alsamixer` via Terminal and check out the headphones column. If it's at 0, increase the volume. At least in my case, every time I log in into my Xubuntu account sound doesn't come out although Master is above zero and I have to set a higher Headphones value manually. I hope it's only a temporary bug that will be fixed soon.